# Numpy operation on Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Is there a way I can use the equivalent of something like numpy.amax on a pandas dataframe?

Currently I do the following with ndarrays:

```
max_result = np.amax((arr1-arr2, arr3-arr4), axis=0)
```

where each of those arrays are 1 column

If those arrays are DataFrames, can I still do element-wise operations on them?

EDIT:
(didn't give enough original information)
When using the arrays, `max_result` is an array of the maximum of the 2 differences above.

However if those are dataframes, I get the following error:
"ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Comment: Have you tried this? It should work.

Comment: Sorry, what should I try?  Thanks

Comment: `max_result = np.amax(df, axis=0)` works for me, it should work for you. The point being asking if something can be done without trying is not a good question.

Comment: My bad - the question was worded poorly.  Please see EDIT above.

Comment: Break the question down into smaller chunks.  Does `arr1-arr2` work for you?  Does `(arr1-arr2, arr3-arr4)` give you what you want?  I suspect you get a tuple of DataFrames, which is probably not what you want; you might want to use [concatenate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) first.  Also, one nice way to get an array out of a DataFrame is to use [the `.values` attribute](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#attributes-and-the-raw-ndarray-s).

Comment: @Mike - Thanks.  I just used the .values attribute and it worked like a charm.  I'm obviously new so don't think I'm formatting everything properly within the stack overflow site.

Comment: Great!  You should probably show what you did in an answer, so that other people searching can see what works.  And then you should be able to accept that answer after a while, so other people won't come and try to answer a question that's already resolved.  And welcome to the site!  :)

Answer (score 0):

@Mike gave the tip of using the [.values](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#attributes-and-the-raw-ndarray-s) attribute.  So the line of code above becomes:

```
max_result = np.amax((arr1.values-arr2.values, arr3.values-arr4.values), axis=0)
```